# React + Typescript + Dynamic import HOC typings

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, dynamic-import

```
import React from 'react'
import { Preloader } from 'src/base-components/preloader'
import styles from './styles.scss'

const withLazyLoading = (importComponent: any) => {
    return class extends React.Component {
        public state = {
            component: null
        }

        public componentDidMount() {
            importComponent()
                .then((cmp) => {
                    this.setState({ component: cmp.default })
                })
        }

        public render() {
            const Component = this.state.component
            return Component
                ? <Component { ...this.props } />
                : <div className={ styles.box }><Preloader show /></div>
        }
    }
}

export { withLazyLoading }
```

I'd like to add Types for:

> importComponent: any **<= not to be any**

Everything works Ok, but `any` causes an error:

[image]

Comment: Please include the actual code, rather than a picture of code, so that people can try to reproduce your problem without retyping it.

Answer (score 0):

Given `importComponent` is a *function* that returns a *promise* of a component, it is:

```
const withLazyLoading = (importComponent: () => Promise<React.ComponentClass>) => {
...
```

It can be additionally typed as a generic if needed:

```
const withLazyLoading = <T extends {}>(importComponent: () => Promise<React.ComponentClass<T>>): React.ComponentClass<T> => {
    return class extends React.Component<T> {
    ...
```